# Why do I hear voices when I touch my turntable needle?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electronics, radio, antennas

So I was trying to figure out the reason why my old (and probably sufficiently damaged) needle on my phonograph (turntable) was not working like it was a little while ago.

With my headphones on, I was playing around with it and happened to touch two of the leads on the underbody of the needle.

[image: The needle]

All of a sudden, a man's voice was speaking to me in a muffled, mid-pass tone, slightly audible but definitely discernible (talking about the "nightmares of the Obama regime" or something odd like that).

The voices only occurred when I was in contact with both leads.

---

Why is this? Did I turn myself into a giant watery antenna? I know phonographs have some interesting physics to them, but this is a new one. Why is it so clear? I can hardly get old analog radios to focus cleanly, let alone my own body. Is there a natural resonance that caused such a clear audio frequency to be heard?

Comment: Possibly related:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio

Comment: There are two types of pickup: the crystal type and the magnetic (coil) type. If this is a crystal type, then you did turn yourself into an antenna and the crystal into the demodulator. The amplifier did the rest... If it's a coil type, it is possible that together you were tuned "just so", setting up a resonance (with the wiring acting as the capacitive element perhaps?)

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I thought about it; I almost posted it there. It didn't seem like the best fit, though. This is more of an electromagnetic physics question to me; I'm looking more for why my body was the "missing link" of sorts. I think there is a little overlap, which is probably innocuous.

Comment: Did you ask someone else to try it and see if they had a different frequency?

Comment: @Floris Crystal pickups are _ancient_ technology.  AFAIK, they were only ever used in "toy" phonographs, not in hi-fi equipment like what is shown in the picture.  It's much more likely that some metal oxide particle at the point of contact between the OP's ear-buds and the wires on the bottom of the cartridge was acting as a crude rectifier.  It's also possible that the _coils_ in the magnetic pickup played a role (e.g., resonant with the radio signal?)

Comment: @jameslarge I had a non toy crystal pickup. High impedance, high voltage, different equalization than magnetic (no RIAAA eq needed). Thanks for telling me I'm ancient... I agree that this specimen most likely is magnetic and that the coil is part of the resonant circuit as I stated in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Floris, P.S., the crystal in a crystal radio was a _semiconductor_ crystal (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galena).  The crystal in a "crystal" pickup is a piezoelectric crystal or ceramic chip.

Comment: Link to the cartridge shown; http://www.stantondj.com/stanton-cartridges/500v3.html

Comment: @jameslarge - you are right, in itself a piezo transducer may not have the rectifying properties needed to act as a detector. The link I posted confirms this is a dynamic (magnetic) pickup. That leaves unanswered the question "what is acting as the detector / demodulator"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your phonograph cartridge uses a piezo-electric pickup, the cartridge may have acted as a rudimentary crystal radio receiver.  In a piezo-electric pickup, the stylus contacts a crystal and creates an electric current while jiggling as it moves through the grooves of a record.  It's likely that while you were jiggling the apparatus, you found the exact contact between stylus and crystal which created a natural resonance that was activated by the radio frequency passing into the crystal.  Just by chance, the resonance of your crystal may have exactly matched the frequency of a talk-radio station.  Crystal radios can be powered by the radio waves they receive. All you need for a crystal radio is an antenna, headphones, a detector consisting of stylus and crystal, a tuning coil, and a ground: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio#/media/File:CrystalRadio.jpg.  If the position and pressure of the stylus on your crystal established a natural resonance in agreement with the frequency of the station you received, you could do without the tuning coil.

Here is a link to the various types of phonograph cartridges: http://www.enjoythemusic.com/cartridgehistory.htm.  Scroll down to Piezoelectric Pickups for a description of what I think you may have.  Perhaps your body acted as the antenna.  Here is a link explaining some of the aspects of the human body as antenna: http://www.jpier.org/PIER/pier148/17.14061207.pdf.